# How to initiate a view in class, and then call it in another activity?

Tags: java, android, arrays, class, android-activity

Basically, I am programming a reversi game for android, and I have a singlePlayerGame activity, and a Position class. I am trying to set up the board using an array of imageViews that act as buttons which represent chess board squares. The problem is the when the button is initiallised in the Position class, it needs a context, but will not let me have getApplicationContext().

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried passing the context to the Position class constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hazard1994: You can pass the context to the Position class constructor like this:

```
     class Position{
        Context myContext;

        //Constructor
        public Position( Context context){
          myContext = context;
        }

        //Then you can do anything with myContext variable
      }
```

When initial Position object in your activity, you can pass context to it.

```
     Position pos = new Position(getApplicationContext());
```

If you use array position, you must initial all objects like this:

```
     Position[][] pos = new Position[8][8];
     //initial for all objects in array
     for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
           pos[i][j] = new Position(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Ah! I have this initialisation loop elsewere in the program, but its just pos[i][j] = new Position();

Answer (score 2):

Make a constructor for your Position class that accepts a `Context` object.  When you create the instance of the Position class, pass in the context.  Use that context to make your buttons.  Just keep in mind that you have to change the context to the new context if you do an orientation change or if the activity restarts next time (you need to do that with the `ImageViews` anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the quck help, but how do I pass in the context? I set up a new array of positions in the singlePlayerGame activity with final Position[][] board = new Position[8][8];

Comment: R4j has the example.  `Context` is an object that you can pass to other objects just like anything else.  You don't need to do any fancy Android stuff.  You make the constructor accept it to help ensure that your `Position` object will always have one

Answer (score 2):

If I understood properly, you are trying to hold Board cells as ImageViews/Buttons in your Position class. And to instantiate them you need Context which typically in Activity we get by calling getApplicationContext(). If so, I feel passing the Context as constructor parameter is the easiest way and then use the same in constructing Image/Buttons in Position Class.